# Cite Powerpoint lecture

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I need to cite powerpoint slides from online lecture in my reference section. I just started using latex today, and I am using `biblatex`, APA style for my cites. So far I have:

```
@online{slides_on_ABC,
author={Joe and John},
title = {Title of the slides},
url = {https://mail.yahoo.com/},
urldate = {2020-07-24}
}
```

I want to include "[Powerpoint Slides]", as this is apart of the APA 7th edition citation.

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex-apa` comes with a comprehensive example `.bib` file that contains entries for almost all entries in the APA manual.

For slides we find the following two entries in [`biblatex-apa-test-references.bib`, ll. 2282-2301](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/0cffc8636dd2ffd8955c1e90e76fb70c237be584/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib#L2282-LL2301).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@IMAGE{10.14:102b,
  ENTRYSUBTYPE   = {powerpoint},
  AUTHOR         = {Brian Housand},
  TITLE          = {Game on! {Integrating} Games and Simulations in the Classroom},
  PUBLISHER      = {SlideShare},
  DATE           = {2016},
  URL            = {https://www.slideshare.net/brianhousand/game-on-iagc-2016/}
}
@IMAGE{10.14:102c,
  ENTRYSUBTYPE   = {powerpoint},
  AUTHOR         = {R. Mack and G. Spake},
  TITLE          = {Citing Open Source Images and Formatting References for
                    Presentations},
  PUBLISHER      = {Canvas@FNU},
  DATE           = {2018},
  URL            = {https://fnu.onelogin.com/login}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,10.14:102b,10.14:102c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Housand, B. (2016). Game on! Integrating games and simulations in the classroom [Powerpoint slides]. SlideShare. https://www.slideshare.net/brianhousand/game-on-iagc-2016/ Mack, R., & Spake, G. (2018). Citing open source images and formatting references for presentations [Powerpoint slides]. Canvas@FNU. https://fnu.onelogin.com/login]